# How would I get my Java Scanner to read in these strings from this file?

Tags: java, arrays, input, io, java.util.scanner

I have this input file:

```
6
8
ABBEJCDD
ULSCALAR
FUGLVRUT
STOUASTO
STOALGOT
LALGOSLU
8
SCALA
JAVA
ALGOS
ALGORITHM
SLUG
SLUR
GOES
TURTLE
```

Currently, what I have it doing is reading the first two items, which are ints, and adding them to an ArrayList. I then want to read only the next 6 lines up to and not including the "8" and add them to an array.

How would I modify my code to do so?

```
    Scanner fileScanner = null;
    File inFile = new File("input.dat");

    ArrayList<Integer> rc = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("The input has been loaded successfully.");

        while (fileScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int tempRowsCols = fileScanner.nextInt();
            rc.add(tempRowsCols);
        } // end while

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(fileScanner.next());
        }
    } // end try

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Did not work.");
    }
```

Comment: So, what you are trying to do is read that there is a grid, of 6-by-8 characters, and then, you have to search that grid for the next 8 words?

Comment: @rolfl yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @jdc987 you want to read **only** the next 6? Or you want the amount of strings to be determined by the number you read? If so, What is the purpose of the 8 in the second line?

Comment: @rolfl the 8 is the number of words I need to find in that grid, and the words after the 8 are the words I need to find.

Comment: OK, i think i got it. You use the second 8 as a marker from where to start reading 8 words?

Comment: The 6 is the number of rows of words in the grid, and the 8 is the number of columns in the grid. The second 8 is the number of words I need to find in the 6x8 grid.

Comment: @nem yeah, thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is looking to have the code read the data in a different way. The assumption is that the first two values are integers, and represent the height, and width of the text grid.

```
// read the width and height
int height = scan.nextInt();
int width = scan.nextInt();
// build the 2D array to store the char grid.
char[][] chars = new char[height][];
for (int line = 0; line < height; line++) {
    chars[line] = scan.next().toCharArray();
}
```

Then you get the 8 to indicate there are 8 words, followed by the words:

```
// get the number of words to expect
int wordcount = scan.nextInt();
// make a place to store the words.
String[] words = new String[wordcount];
for (int i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) {
    words[i] = scan.next();
}
```

This will give you the data in a 2d char array, and the words in a String array....

Comment: How would I access the chars array and words array outside of the try/catch loop?

Comment: That would be doing a lot more of your homework than just a little bit, but as a hint, you should probably put the two code sections in my answer in to two functions, one returning the char[][] grid, the other returning the words. Then, use those to build a class that you use to solve the puzzle/search.

Comment: So do they even need to be in a try/catch loop?

Comment: You should always have a strategy for catching exceptions, so, yes. What that strategy is often depends on how 'serious' your program is, and how critical the work being done is. For robust code, and quality reporting, then yes, you should have a logging system, try/catch blocks, and more

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you question is a little ambiguous but is this what you had in mind? I don't see the purpose of the `ArrayList<Integer>`'s so I just read the rows and columns directly:

```
try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("The input has been loaded successfully.");

        String rows = fileScanner.next();   // read the number of rows
        String cols = fileScanner.next();   // read the number of columns
        String token = fileScanner.next();  // read next token
        System.out.println("\n\tROWS (" + rows + ")\n");
        while (!token.equals(cols)) {  // while token doesn't equal to the number of columns, keep read tokens
            System.out.println("\t" + token);
            token = fileScanner.next();
        }
        int colsInt = Integer.parseInt(token); // get number of columns as an int
        System.out.println("\n\tCOLS (" + cols + ")\n"); // read that many tokens
        for (int i = 0; i < colsInt; i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + fileScanner.next());
        }
    } // end try
```

OUTPUT:

```
ROWS (6)

ABBEJCDD
ULSCALAR
FUGLVRUT
STOUASTO
STOALGOT
LALGOSLU

COLS (8)

SCALA
JAVA
ALGOS
ALGORITHM
SLUG
SLUR
GOES
TURTLE
```

**Note** if your file isn't in this format, this code will break.

In general, if you don't know how many `int` or `Strings` you want to read, you could make a single loop and then read one token at a time and then perform appropriate operation depending if it is a `String` or an `int`:

```
while(fileScanner.hasNext() {
    if(fileScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        // process int
    } else {
        // process string
    }
}
```

Comment: Good advice on the `hasNext()`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> fileStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fis);
while((String tempVar = reader.readLine()) != "8")   // or whatever you want your reader to stop at
{
  fileStrings.add(tempVar);
}

for(String x : fileStrings) System.out.println(x);
```